# UITabBarControllerでの切り替えに応じた処理について(Swift)

Tags: swift

UITabBarControllerでの切り替えに応じた処理について質問なのですが、
storyboardにてtag番号を設置し、それぞれの切り替え時に効果音を鳴らすとします。

if文で「if(item.tag == 1)」などと分岐するのは思い浮かんだのですが、
UITabBarItemと連動させるコードが分かりません。

Objective-Cでの切り替え方法などはこちらのサイト(http://teapipin.blog10.fc2.com/blog-entry-66.html)で拝見させて頂いたのですが、＜２．タブの切り替え時のアクション＞という部分で合っているのかさえよく理解できませんでした。

お詳しい方がいましたら、ご回答宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ポイントと言うほどでもないですが、以下が必要です。

1. `UITabBarDelegate`の継承
2. [`tabBar:didSelectItem:`メソッド](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITabBarDelegate/tabBar:didSelectItem:)の実装(＜２．タブの切り替え時のアクション＞に該当)
3. `UITabBar`へのdelegateの設定
4. `UITabBarItem`へのtagの設定

1～3は以下のようになります。

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITabBarDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        // let tabBarController = UITabBarController()の場合
        tabBarController.tabBar.delegate = self
    }

    func tabBar(tabBar: UITabBar, didSelectItem item: UITabBarItem!) {
        // TODO:選択時の処理
    }
}
```

Comment: 回答有り難うございます。そこで質問なのですが、「let tabBarController = UITabBarController()の場合」とはどういうことでしょうか？コードにてUITabBarControllerを生成している、ということでしょうか？また、4.のtagの設定というのはstoryboard上にて「BatItem」のtagの数字を設定するだけで大丈夫でしょうか(コーディングしなくてもよいのか、という意味)？
未熟者の上、長文で申し訳ないのですが教えて頂けると嬉しいです。

Comment: 直前の質問が`UITabBarController`の作成にStoryboardを利用していなかったのでそのように書いてあります。Storyboardで設定しているのであれば問題ないと思いますが、`UITabBarDelegate`をStoryboardから指定できたかどうかは確証が無いです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。試行錯誤してみます。