# UITabBarControllerにて、それぞれのViewで異なる効果音を鳴らす

Tags: swift, storyboard, uitabbarcontroller

storyboardで生成したUITabBarControllerを用いて、それぞれのViewで異なる効果音を鳴らし、TabBarをタップすると、他のViewに遷移したときに元いたViewの効果音を止める、という動作を書きたいのですが、
とりあえず分かっていることは「viewDidLoadに効果音再生のコードを書く」ということだけで、
前の質問([UITabBarControllerでの切り替えに応じた処理について(Swift)](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/5924/uitabbarcontroller)%E3%81%A7%E6%95%99%E3%81%88%E3%81%A6%E9%A0%82%E3%81%84%E3%81%9F)、TabBarItemのボタンの原理はイマイチよく理解できませんでした。

(前の質問で言うと `tabBarController.tabBar.delegate = self` で「delegateというクラスは存在しない」と表示され、つまづきました。)

storyboardでのView内では一つしかTabBarItemが表示されていないので、該当する全てのViewに同じコードを書かなければならないのですか？
UITabBarItemにActionがあれば楽なのですが……

```js
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class HomeView: UIViewController, AVAudioPlayerDelegate, UITabBarDelegate {

    //サウンドの変数宣言
    var myTabSound: AVAudioPlayer!

    @IBOutlet weak var myTabBar: UITabBarItem!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        myTabBar.tabBar.delegate = self
        //↑ここでつまづき、他に思いつくdelegateを含むコードを書いてもエラーになる

        //サウンドのソースコード生成
        let soundFilePath: NSString = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("effect8", ofType: "mp3")!
        let fileURL : NSURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: soundFilePath)!
        //AVAudioPlayerのインスタンス化
        myTabSound = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: fileURL, error: nil)
        //AVAudioPlayerのデリゲートをセット
        myTabSound.delegate = self
    }

    func tabBar(tabBar: UITabBar, didSelectItem item: UITabBarItem!) {
        if(item.tag == 1){
            //効果音を鳴らす
            myTabSound.play()
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

お詳しい方がいましたら、どうか回答宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: Delegateは、UIKit（iOSの、GUIを構成するフレームワーク）で多用される、重要な機構なので、これを理解しないと、iOSのプログラミングはできませんし、他人の書いたプログラムも、解読不可能です。基礎ができていないと、なにをやっても中途半端で終わってしまいます。基本に戻って、Delegateの勉強をやり直してください。すくなくとも、「Delegateってなんですか？」と問われて、こういうものだよと他人に説明できるくらいにはなってください。

Comment: @らりん 「tabBarController.tabBar.delegate = self」のところでエラー(赤いヤツ)が出る理由は、myTabBarがUITabBarControllerクラスのインスタンスではなく、UITabBarItemクラスのインスタンスだからですね。各クラスのプロパティは、リファレンスを確認してから使用する事をお勧めします。リファレンスの簡単な確認方法は、ソースコード上で任意のクラス名や変数名をalt(option)キーを押しながら選択すると出てくるポップアップ上の"Reference"のリンクから確認できます。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UITabBarのDelegate先は、UITabBarControllerに固定されているようです。プログラムで変更すると、アプリがエラーで落ちます。

1. なので、UITabBarControllerのサブクラスを作り、Storyboard上でTabBar
   Controllerのクラスを変更。 Delegateメソッドは、UITabBarControllerサブクラスに記述。
2. UITabBarControllerが、UITabBarDelegateを実装しているので、サブクラスに再実装する必要はなし。
3. Delegateメソッドにはoverrideオプションをつける。

私の考えでは、UITabBarDelegateを使わずに、**UITabBarControllerDelegate**を使って、TabBar Itemタップ時の処理を行うほうが、いいでしょう。UITabBarControllerDelegateは、アプリ起動時、存在するインスタンスなら、実装できます。
（最初のタブのViewController以外は、タップして表示するまで、生成されていませんので、注意してください）
UITabBarControllerDelegateのメソッド「optional func **tabBarController**(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, **didSelectViewController** viewController: UIViewController)」を利用するのがいいでしょう。

Comment: @Harawo様、回答ありがとうございます。実装できました！ご丁寧な回答、本当に有り難うございます。